# Gulp ftp deploy. Without src directory

Tags: ftp, gulp

I'm trying to figure out how to send files without `src` dir when gulp is deploying dist on ftp server.

My config:

```
var gutil = require( 'gulp-util' );
var ftp = require( 'vinyl-ftp' );

gulp.task( 'deploy', function() {

    var conn = ftp.create( {
        host:     'hydrogen',
        user:     'hosting',
        password: 'test',
        parallel: 10,
        log:      gutil.log
    } );

    var globs = [
        'src/**',
        'css/**',
        'js/**',
        'fonts/**',
        'index.html'
    ];

    // using base = '.' will transfer everything to /public_html correctly
    // turn off buffering in gulp.src for best performance

    return gulp.src( globs, { base: '.', buffer: false } )
        .pipe( conn.newer( '/projects/test' ) ) // only upload newer files
        .pipe( conn.dest( '/projects/test' ) );

} );
```

So, after deploy I get `projects/test/src` path. I want to get files without `src` dir or rename it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [flatten](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-flatten) to remove the path information from the files.